# Кодировка параметров SOAP WSDL из PHP

Tags: php, node.js, wsdl, криптопро

Передаю в SoapClient параметр 123, а в трассировке получаю такой параметр: "MTIz" и из-за этого преобразования весь WSDL не работает!

Передаю в SOAPUI  то, что показывает в трассировке и получаю аналогичную ошибку! При этом, стойкое ощущение, что если бы не подобное преобразование, то работало бы нормально!

В SOAP UI все четко: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
ОДно замечание - когда вставляю в SOAPUI ссылку на WSDL, то запросы автоматом идут на  https://ssd.marinet.ru/ssd/LiteService.svc/cert, и стоит мне убрать /cert из урл, то сразу работает! 
Пытался на NODEJS сделать, там ошибка с SSL (iss-овская ошибка):

> Ошибка HTTP 403.7 — Forbidden
>   Страница, к которой вы пытаетесь обратиться, требует, чтобы веб-браузер имел SSL-сертификат клиента, признаваемый веб-сервером.
>   ...
>   ....

Эта ошибка означает, что для доступа к запрошенному URL-адресу нужно использовать протокол SSL. Сертификат клиента используется для подтверждения ваших прав как законного пользователя этого ресурса. С вопросами о том, как получить корректный сертификат для использования на веб-сайте, обращайтесь к администратору сайта

КОД NODEJS:

```html
var url = 'http://ssd.marinet.ru/ssd/LiteService.svc?wsdl';
var soap = require('soap');
var express = require('express');

 
 
var args = {name: 'value'};
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    console.log(client)
    console.log(`
    ==========================================
    `)
    client.PreSignDocument(args, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Работаю с (собственным) dss-lite сервером КриптоПро

Сам WSDL можно здесь посмотреть:
https://ssd.marinet.ru/ssd/LiteService.svc?wsdl

Вот код:

```
$url = 'https://ssd.marinet.ru/ssd/LiteService.svc?wsdl';
$document =123;
$rawCertificate ='123';

  $soap_params = [
                    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                    'trace' => 1, 
                    'exceptions'     => true,    
                    'verifypeer' => false,
                    'verifyhost' => false,       
                    'cache_wsdl'     => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,                   
                    'encoding'=>'UTF-8',
                    'connection_timeout'=>15000,
                    'style'=>SOAP_RPC,
                    'uri'=>'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',   //   "urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes",  // Пространство имен SOAP-метода 
                    "soapaction" => "urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes#getQuote",  // HTTP-заголовок SOAPAction  для SOAP-метода 
                    "use"      => SOAP_ENCODED,
                    "location" => $url
                ];


var_dump( $soap_service);
    $soap_service = new SoapClient( $url, $soap_params );

    echo '<h1>FUNCTIONS:</h1>';
    print_r($soap_service->__getTypes   ());

    echo '<h1>Response:</h1>';
    $res = $soap_service->PreSignDocument([     'document'       => $document,
                                                    'rawCertificate'       => $rawCertificate,  
                                                    'signatureType'        => 'PDF',                                          
                                                    'signatureParams'       => array()
                                    ]);
var_dump($res);


}catch(Exception $e){

    echo '<h1>err:</h1>';
    echo $soap_service->__getLastRequest();
    die($e->getMessage());

}
```

На выходе:

```
FUNCTIONS:
Array ([0] => struct ArrayOfKeyValueOfSignatureParamsstring1Iy7z97I { 

KeyValueOfSignatureParamsstring1Iy7z97I KeyValueOfSignatureParamsstring1Iy7z97I; }
[1] => struct KeyValueOfSignatureParamsstring1Iy7z97I { SignatureParams Key; string Value; }
[2] => string SignatureType
[3] => string SignatureParams
[4] => struct DSSPreSignResponse { base64Binary HashValue; string СacheObjectId; }
[5] => struct DssFault { string Message; }
[6] => struct DSSLitePolicy { ArrayOfSignatureType AllowedSignatureTypes; ArrayOfTspService TspServices; }
[7] => struct ArrayOfSignatureType { SignatureType SignatureType; }
[8] => struct ArrayOfTspService { TspService TspService; }
[9] => struct TspService { string Name; string Title; string Url; }
[10] => struct PreSignArgs { base64Binary document; base64Binary rawCertificate; ArrayOfKeyValueOfSignatureParamsstring1Iy7z97I signatureParams; SignatureType signatureType; }
[11] => struct PostSignArgs { string cacheObjectId; ArrayOfKeyValueOfSignatureParamsstring1Iy7z97I signatureParams; SignatureType signatureType; base64Binary signatureValue; base64Binary signedHashValue; }
[12] => struct EnhanceSignatureArgs { base64Binary document; ArrayOfKeyValueOfSignatureParamsstring1Iy7z97I signatureParams; SignatureType signatureType; }
[13] => struct PreSignDocument { base64Binary document; SignatureType signatureType; base64Binary rawCertificate; ArrayOfKeyValueOfSignatureParamsstring1Iy7z97I signatureParams; }
[14] => struct PreSignDocumentResponse { DSSPreSignResponse PreSignDocumentResult; }
[15] => struct PostSignDocument { string cacheObjectId; base64Binary signedHashValue; base64Binary signatureValue; SignatureType signatureType; ArrayOfKeyValueOfSignatureParamsstring1Iy7z97I signatureParams; }
[16] => struct PostSignDocumentResponse { base64Binary PostSignDocumentResult; }
[17] => struct EnhanceSignature { base64Binary document; SignatureType signatureType; ArrayOfKeyValueOfSignatureParamsstring1Iy7z97I signatureParams; }
[18] => struct EnhanceSignatureResponse { base64Binary EnhanceSignatureResult; }
[19] => struct GetPolicy { }
[20] => struct GetPolicyResponse { DSSLitePolicy GetPolicyResult; }
[21] => struct PreSignDocumentRest { PreSignArgs preSignArguments; }
[22] => struct PreSignDocumentRestResponse { DSSPreSignResponse PreSignDocumentRestResult; }
[23] => struct PostSignDocumentRest { PostSignArgs postSignArgs; }
[24] => struct PostSignDocumentRestResponse { base64Binary PostSignDocumentRestResult; }
[25] => struct EnhanceSignatureRest { EnhanceSignatureArgs enhanceSignatureArgs; }
[26] => struct EnhanceSignatureRestResponse { base64Binary EnhanceSignatureRestResult; }
[27] => struct GetPolicyRest { }
[28] => struct GetPolicyRestResponse { DSSLitePolicy GetPolicyRestResult; }
[29] => int char
[30] => duration duration
[31] => string guid
)
Response:
err:
MTIzPDFMTIz Требуемый объект не найден.
```

Comment: В поле DOCUMENT шлю PDF-документ в base64,
В rawCertificate  => сертификат в base64

Comment: Нашел в  WSDL следующую строку:<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_ILiteService1" binding="i0:BasicHttpBinding_ILiteService1">
<soap:address location="https://ssd.marinet.ru/ssd/LiteService.svc/cert"/>
</wsdl:port>

Comment: что с ней можно делать? похоже изза него на CERT идет запрос.. А надо бы убрать CERT!

Comment: Сохраните wsdl локально и уберите лишний порт.

Comment: ДЕМО PHP СМОТРЕТЬ ЗДЕСЬ: https://www.tehplayground.com/rv4lUYH4xPOzRF4S

Comment: Доступа к WSDL же нету! У меня только DLL !

Comment: Как у вас может не быть доступа к wsdl когда вы сами привели URL?

Comment: Хорошо, я сохранил - https://ssd.marinet.ru/LiteService.xml изменил и получил в ответ NULL